# Generate a query that show the times that questions get wrong

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table named `countwronganswer` with columns `cwa_id`, `question_num`.  How can I generate a table with query that shows two columns, one column lists all the `question_num` and second column lists the number of times that `cwa_id` that related to the `question_num`.

```
Question Number |Total # of Mistake | 
1                12
2                22
..etc
```

**ATTENTION: This question was asked without the awareness of the existence of count or Groupby method because of the knowledge level at that state. Count() or Groupby() were the key to generate the 2nd column of total # values which I did not aware of completely, therefore, any attempt, at that point of time, to write the code for the data will be close to meaningless. *Vote up if possible if you think its useful or resolved your issue.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something like this

```
SELECT question_num, COUNT(cwa_id) total_mistakes
  FROM countwronganswer
 GROUP BY question_num
```

Comment: great! I am glad you did not vote down, but provided a wonderful solution! Thank you sincerely. :)

Comment: also I asked a meta question for this:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187050/lots-of-vote-down-on-the-question-suggestion-to-improve

Comment: Use your rep to tell those people! @peterm

Answer (score 1):

```
select question_num , count(cwa_id)
 from tableName group by question_num
```